# gsub on last special character

Tags: r, regex, split, gsub

I want to get two strings that occurs before and after last special character (i.e. _).

```
one <- c("TRANS-PLATINUM_(II)_DIAMMINE_DICHLORIDE_kidney")
```

I expect result

```
string1 = TRANS-PLATINUM_(II)_DIAMMINE_DICHLORIDE

string2 = kidney
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use

```
scan(text=sub("(.*)_([^_]+)$", "\\1,\\2", one), sep=",", what ='', quiet = TRUE)
#[1] "TRANS-PLATINUM_(II)_DIAMMINE_DICHLORIDE" "kidney"
```

Or using only `strsplit`

```
strsplit(one, "_(?=[^_]+$)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
strsplit(two, "_(?=[^_]+$)", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "N,N-DIMETHYLFORMAMIDE" "kidney"
```

#### data

```
two <- "N,N-DIMETHYLFORMAMIDE_kidney"
```

Comment: there is no special structure for part of string e.g. I want to do same operation for N,N-DIMETHYLFORMAMIDE_kidney and many more

Comment: @mr_swap  It is not clear about expected output for the example you commented

Comment: @mr_swap  Is it to be split into `N,N-DIMETHYLFORMAMIDE` and `kidney` in that case it works